# Do Warhammer models that have no models have specific dimensions stated any where?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tyranids

I have made some tyranid mycetic spores by just covering a dreadnought sized base in some green putty to show how the spore burst when it hit the ground. I have seen many mycetic spore conversions and everyone seems to lean towards making them as tall as space marine drop pods. I am worried about using these in any type of tournament setting because they would be hard to draw true line of site to. When I have played against players in the past I have allowed them to draw line of site to the pods based on them being roughly drop pod sized.

This got me wondering if their was a official source for the dimensions of models that do not have official models?

Also if forge world makes a model is it then considered official for base size and dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question really ends up being no.  Units with no purchasable model have no defined dimensions, and so are up to you and your opponent as to what is reasonable.

However, as of the most recent codex and updates, the Mycetic Spore is no longer a valid unit.  It has since been replaced with the Tyrannocyte, which serves largely the same purposes.  This unit does have a model, and is, as expected, about as large as a drop pod.  If you want to continue using the Mycetic Spore in friendly games, make sure you and your opponent agree on size, line of sight and rules before beginning.

As an aside, the reason for the change between Mycetic Spores and Tyrannocytes are largely legal, and there's quite the backstory behind the removal of the Mycetic spore option.  It's worth looking into if you're curious.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know they had removed the myscetic spore. Do you have a link to the story of why it was removed?

Comment: The short of it is that they had the unit without a model, so another studio made a model that became the de-facto standard model.  (Chapterhouse Studios, IIRC).  GW did not like that someone else's model had become the standard, and apparently, there were concerns that releasing their own at that point could possibly cause some kind of legal concern.  So, they killed it and changed the concept enough to be something else, the Tyrannocyte.  [1d4chan](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Mycetic_Spore) has some info, but I can't verify that link has the whole story, as I don't recommend visiting at work...

Comment: Yeah I have been to 1d4chan. It has a lot of good information but it is horrible to sift through all the garbage in between the good information.